# Remove the duplicates from a list and move the the other duplicate on top of the list

Tags: java

I'm trying to test a code that if I add new element to the list it detects the similar element and remove one of the duplicates but move the other one to the beginning of the list.

```
public class MemberList {

    List<String> members;

    public MemberList() {
        this.members = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    //This is the part I'm trying to fix!!!
    public void addMember(String FirstName, String LastName) {
        members.add(0, FirstName + " " + LastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make you use ArrayList methods contains() and remove() and add() to get this done.For efficiency purpose , it would be better to go with a Set.

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: I have posted the answer for solution using list.However,i really urge you to understand the sets and lists difference and use cases.

Comment: Also recommend you be a little more specific with what is going wrong, what have you done to try and fix the issue, what error messages are you getting, etc

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ArrayList, I think you should use LinkedHashSet as no duplicated elements are allowed in your collection. And LinkedHashSet will reserve insertion order so when you detect a duplicate, you can remove old one and insert new one to set.

```
public class MemberList {

    Set<String> members;

    public MemberList() {
        this.members = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    }

    public void addMember(String FirstName, String LastName) {
        String key = FirstName + " " + LastName;
        if (members.contains(key)) {
            members.remove(key);
        }
        members.add(key); // Always add to tail
    }
}
```

Remember LinkedHashSet will always add new elements to the tail, so you need to get last element for your beginning case.

Comment: `new LinkedHashSet<>();` - no need to mention the datatype here. And you are not going to mention anything about java naming convention?

Comment: I just copy his code and make some update. Diss him if you want.

Answer (score 0):

List way to accomplish the task (not preferred due to efficiency):

```
public void addMember(String FirstName, String LastName) {
    String name = FirstName+" "+LastName;

    if(members.contains(name)) {  // checks if the list contains name value 
        members.remove(name);     // removes the first occurrence of the name from the list
        members.add(0,name);  // adds the name to 0th position of the list
    } else {
        members.add(name);   // if name not found in list, appends the value to the list
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient. A Set is a much better option.

Comment: I have commented the same.But the user have asked for List way explicitly.